# How to detect collision and fill a shape inside a spirograph on.click, using Python Turtle module

Tags: python, collision-detection, turtle-graphics, fill, python-turtle

On this little game there are two characters.

1. Mrs Drawer
2. Mr Filler

First Mrs Drawer, start drawing a spirograph and waits for you to send the Mr Filler to fill inside her newly created shape. She has so many shapes now to be filled. All you need is to send the Mr Filler inside any of the shapes to fill it by a simple click. Once that shape is filled you can send the Mr filler to any other empty shapes to fill.

There is a problem on my code and to tackle the problem first the `move_filler_till_colliding_drawer()` function needs to fixed so that Mr Filler can detect the edge of Mrs Drawer in order to place his pen down and start filling her shape by following along her shape until it gets back to it's initial location and then the filling would end leaving one of her shape in green color.

```
import turtle as t
import random

drawer = t.Turtle()
drawer.hideturtle()
drawer.goto(0, 0)
filler = t.Turtle()
filler.goto(0, 0)
screen = t.Screen()
screen.setup(width=1080, height=720)
screen.title("Draw and Fill Your Shapes")
drawer.speed("fastest")
filler.speed("fast")

drawer_segments = []


def random_color():
    r = random.randint(0, 255)
    g = random.randint(0, 255)
    b = random.randint(0, 255)
    color = (r, g, b)
    return color


def draw_circle(user_choice, num_shapes):
    for _ in range(int(num_shapes)):
        drawer.color(random_color())
        drawer_segments.append([])
        drawer.circle(user_choice)
        drawer_segments[-1].append(drawer.pos())  # Add the segment endpoint
        drawer.setheading(drawer.heading() + int(360 / num_shapes))


# Record the points visited by Mrs Drawer while drawing a shape
def record_segment(x, y):
    drawer_segments[-1].append((x, y))


def move_filler_till_colliding_drawer():
    for segment in drawer_segments:
        for point in segment:
            while filler.distance(point) > 1:
                filler.forward(1)


def follow_drawer_trace():
    for segment in drawer_segments:
        for point in segment:
            angle = filler.towards(segment[point])
            filler.setheading(angle)
            distance_to_segment = filler.distance(segment[point])
            step_size = 1  # Adjust this value as needed

            while distance_to_segment == step_size:
                filler.forward(step_size)
                distance_to_segment = filler.distance(segment[point])


def fill_shape(x, y, filling_color):
    filler.penup()
    filler.goto(x, y)
    move_filler_till_colliding_drawer()
    filler.pencolor(filling_color)
    filler.pendown()
    filler.begin_fill()
    follow_drawer_trace()
    filler.end_fill()


def start_drawing(x, y):
    screen.colormode(255)
    t.clear()
    radius = 100
    num_shapes = 10
    drawer.penup()
    drawer.goto(x, y)
    drawer.pendown()
    draw_circle(radius, num_shapes)
    record_segment(drawer.xcor(), drawer.ycor())  # Record the segment
    filling_color = "green"
    prompt_to_click("FILL")
    screen.onscreenclick(lambda x, y: fill_shape(x, y, filling_color))


# ask the user to click to continue
def prompt_to_click(action):
    t.penup()
    t.hideturtle()
    t.goto(-250, 320)
    t.color("black")
    t.hideturtle()
    t.write(f"Please click where you would like to {action} your shape!", font=("Arial", 18, "normal"))


# call to action to ask the user to click to continue
prompt_to_click("Fill")
# Set up the click event listener
screen.onscreenclick(start_drawing)

t.done()
```

I am not getting any errors with this code. The only issue is that it's not detecting Mrs Drawer so that it can fill her shape.

Comment: Please hardcode values rather than using user input. It's unclear what needs to be plugged into these boxes to get the shape you're asking about. A deterministic [mcve] would be ideal, but short of that, please provide the values we're supposed to punch in to reproduce the problem. Thanks. That said, while I'm not sure what shape you're making, for a fill to work, usually you'll want to draw around the edge of the shape rather than using criss-cross lines that spirographs generally involve. Turtle won't know how to fill that properly, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Thanks. You can still [edit] the post though to make it easier for people to assist and increase the chances that someone will take the time to write an answer. Stripping the code and problem down to a simpler example helps considerably, otherwise answerers have to do that work on your behalf.

Comment: great, didn't know that, let me see how to edit it now :)

Comment: By the time you try to fill it, the shape is already drawn and detecting collisions won't help you. You'll want to re-draw it with `begin_fill()` and `end_fill()`, respecting the possibility that overlaps/criss-crossed lines may not turn out filled as you expect, as mentioned above. Do you want to make the whole spirograph blue, or just one "petal"?

Comment: Anybody out there that can figur this out?

Comment: just one petal at a time